# How to fix this database (Flask) problem on heroku?

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, flask, sqlalchemy

The app works perfect locally. I hosted the app on heroku, it works - only something with the database (connection of heroku db to my app?) fails.

I already tried some options, but nothing helped, because I am not really sure, what exactly the root of the problem is.

### Problem

That's what I get:
**500 Internal Server Error**

*The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.*

### Logs

Here are the important lines of the logs:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "rjgrfkdjglwftp"
```

And:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "users" does not exist
```

Do I have to push the locally created database too?

It is important to know, that there are no problems locally, so it has something to do either with database or the code on heroku, I am not sure.

DB-Connection Logic:

```
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET_KEY = 'this-really-needs-to-be-changed'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
```

Comment: (a) Your local database is irrelevant; there's no need to `pg:pull`. (b) SQLite and PostgreSQL are different systems. You can't dump a Postgres database to an SQLite database, and it's a good idea to use the same database locally as you're using in production. (c) What is `manage.py deploy`? And what is `manage.py`? Flask didn't have a native CLI interface until recently, and now that it does it presents a `flask <command>` interface. Are you using [`Flask-Script`](https://flask-script.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? (d) Please show us your database connection logic. Are you using `DATABASE_URL`?

Comment: My project is literally the same like this one: https://github.com/alectrocute/flaskSaaS

Comment: Please read [ask]. We're not going to go off-site to dig through your code. It's not specific enough, and links can break which makes your question much less useful to future users. Instead, please include the relevant information _here_, directly in your question. Ideally you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Oh, I didn't know - thanks for the information! I added the DB-connection logic. What are possible roots of the problem? Do you have any thoughts? The connection? The database user of my app?

Comment: The database user is part of the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. What do you do with the `Config` class? (I took at look at the repo you linked to even though it's off-site and I don't see any `class Config` in the repository you linked to.)